# clone() syscall in C and sharing

Tags: c, linux, clone, fork

I'm trying to use a clone() syscall to create a thread which shares resources with the parent process.
In the book I read that if I use the following flags, I will be able to do so:
CLONE_VM | CLONE_FILES | CLONE_SIGHAND | CLONE_FS

But it seems the variables are not being shared.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <linux/sched.h>
#include <string.h>
#define STACK_SIZE 65536
#define BUFSIZE 200
int n = 5;
int Child(void *);
int main() {
    pid_t pid;
    char *stack;
    stack = malloc(STACK_SIZE);
    pid = clone(Child,stack + STACK_SIZE, CLONE_SIGHAND|CLONE_FS|CLONE_VM|CLONE_FILES);
    wait(NULL);
    char buf[BUFSIZE];
    sprintf(buf,"Back to parent: Value of n: %d\n",n);
    write(1,buf,strlen(buf));
    return 0;
}
int Child(void *args) {
    n += 15;
    char buf[BUFSIZE];
    sprintf(buf,"In child: Value of n: %d\n",n); 
    write(1,buf,strlen(buf));
}
```

The output keeps changing as well. I'm confused.

Comment: Sounds like you could just use `pthreads`. Is it really necessary to use a Linux-specific, very complicated system call manually?

Comment: Indeed I can. I just wanted to see how clone() worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int n = 5;
int Child(void *);
int main() {
    int n = 5;
```

You have two variables called `n`. `Child` operates on the global one, but `main` uses the one defined in its scope.

You should also change your `wait` call to `waitpid(-1, NULL, __WALL)`, otherwise you won't actually wait on the cloned process. (Or you could add `|SIGCHLD` to the clone options.)

From the [`clone(2)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/clone.2.html) docs:

> The low byte of flags contains the number of the termination signal sent to
>          the parent when the child dies.  If this signal is specified as anything other
>          than SIGCHLD, then the parent process must specify the __WALL or __WCLONE
>          options when waiting for the child with wait(2).  If no signal is specified,
>          then the parent process is not signaled when the child terminates.

Comment: Whoops, I had added that during debugging and forgot to remove it. The output is still the same when I remove it though.

Comment: Edited it back. The output still is the same. It seems that the child only gets a copy of the global variable and not the global variable itself. So the resources are not being shared at all?

Comment: Your wait call isn't actually waiting for anything.

Comment: It's in the docs. `clone` is a pretty complex call, read the man page carefully.